# Trigger multiple actions on click with toggleClass() in jQuery

Tags: jquery, triggers

I want to trigger several simultaneous actions when I click a button.

In jQuery, I use toggleClass() to show and hide the burger. Unrolling the menu on click works perfectly. What I can't do is to trigger another event simultaneously. For example, hiding an item on the page.

The behavior I want to achieve is the following:
. when I click on the burger, the menu unrolls and hides the item in question
. a new click on the burger brings up the menu and displays again the item that was hidden

I tried a lot of things without success.

A little help ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. If you get stuck, post a minimal reproducible example of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` [snippet editor](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do).

Comment: `$("#buttonId").on("click", $("#burger").toggleClass("active"); $("#someDiv").toggle(); })`  ???

Comment: You might be looking to check `.is(".class")` or `.is(":visible")` / `.is(":hidden")` to see if the menu is already shown/hidden and act accordingly.

Comment: Note: if you include (had included) what you already have, then people won't suggest the basics.  It *looks like* you already have a click event with toggleClass.

Answer (score 1):

For that kind of effect, I typically add a class to whatever container contains both the menu and the thing you want to show/hide (in the worst case, they're both in `body`), then use CSS with a descendant selector to control the menu and the thing. Here's a basic example:

```js
document.getElementById("menu").addEventListener("click", () => {
    document.getElementById("container").classList.toggle("the-class");
});
```

```css
#menu {
    /* Normal styles for the menu */
    border: 1px solid grey;
    height: 5em;
}
.hidey-thing {
    /* Normal styles for the hidey thing if any needed */
}

#container.the-class #menu {
    /* Styles for the menu when toggled */
    height: 10em;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
#container.the-class .hidey-thing {
    /* Styles for the hidey thing when toggled */
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div id="menu">
    The menu
    </div>
    <div class="hidey-thing">
    This is the show/hide thing
    </div>
</div>
```

I didn't use jQuery there because I didn't see the need, but you could:

```
$("#menu").on("click", () => {
    $("#container").toggleClass("the-class");
});
```

Comment: Hmm, clever but confusing

Comment: @mplungjan - It's not particularly either, IMHO; it's common practice.

Comment: First time I see it...

Comment: @mplungjan - That's surprising! :-)

Comment: Yes. I was a bit surprised too. I prefer to have two statements or no JS

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean:

```
$(document).on("click", "#trigger1", function () {
    //code here
});
```

Comment: I don't think this would solve the problem, it does not sound like event delegation is the problem since the click on the burger works fine

Comment: If trigger1 was present at load time, then it is preferable to do `"$("#trigger1").on("click", function () { ... })`